# How to make SQL table column ordinal to another one, making both of them a composite PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am designing a database for a e-commerce site and one of the requirements are that it should be possible the order to be split to multiple payments. After a research (for good practices) found that good way to do it can be the following:

```
TABLE orders
    - order_id: (PK)

TABLE payments
    - order_id: (FK) to orders
    - payments_id: auto incremental (from 1) for each order_id
    (order_id, payment_id): (PK)
```

Should look like this:

```
payments
#order_id      #payment_id
   1424             1
   1424             2
   1424             3
   1523             1
   1513             1
   1513             2
```

What is the best way to do it? Can it be done on database level and if yes (since I am new to relational dbs) - how?

UPDATE:
How to automate the assignment of payment_id so it tracks the current count of payments for each order_id? I can do it on application level, but it will be more expensive and certainly there should be a way to do it on database.

Comment: Your design looks fine to me

Comment: To me too. Just google `MySQL Create relational tables` , you will find explanations there.

Comment: payments_id doesn't need to reset each time.

Comment: @Strawberry good point. So there is no actual benefit of reseting it? Can it be drawback at some point?

Comment: Did you consider trigger?

Comment: For reasons of data integrity (that I confess I don't fully understand), you would probably opt for InnoDB over MyISAM. The former does not support auto_increment in conjunction with a multi-column primary key. Also, the contiguity of the payment_id is largely irrelevant. Despite its name, auto_increment's role isn't to ensure that rows are 'incremental', just that they are sequential, and hence, unique.

Comment: In summary, just make payment_id an auto-incrementing PK, and don't worry about contiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Although you may *think* that you want `payment_id` to be a nice sequential series with no gaps, it is not necessary.  You can just have the date of the payment, or an auto-incremented id, and use that for ordering.

Why not have the column as you describe it?

It is much harder to maintain a sequential column like this than you might imagine.  There is no built-in functionality, so you need to be sure that:

- Two payments at the same time get different ids.
- When a transaction fails (yes, that does happen), then the id does not increment.
- If a payment is deleted or added (in the middle), then all the ids are adjusted.
- If the database is rolled back to an earlier snapshot, then the "next id"s are adjusted appropriately.

These conditions essentially mean lots of locking on the table.  All that locking has a big impact on performance.

An auto-incremented id gets around lots of these issues by allows gaps.  It is also functionality built into the database, so you know that it works.